# How does the flaming sphere reflex save work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, saving-throw

How do I calculate what a successful reflex DC save when trying to dodge against the flaming sphere?

Answer (score 6):

The DC for a saving throw against a spell is 10 + the spell level + the caster's casting stat modifier + any other bonuses, such as the spell focus feat . This is stated in the class descriptions of each class that can cast spells. Flaming Sphere is no exception and I can't see why you'd think it would be.

For example, if the spell was cast by a Wizard with 18 Int, the DC would be 16 (10 base + 2 level + 4 int).

Comment: +1 but I'd  add: +any other special modifiers from feats, class abilities etc. Foe instance a creature from Plane of Fire might have a racial feature that says "+1 to DC of any spell with the [Fire] descriptor.  Granted, these are more rare for evocation type spells than other schools but they do exist.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I always consider "plus any other modifiers" to be a given but I'll edit that in.

Comment: Reference here as well: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#savingThrow.  I did not edit in since you mentioned a reference not this.